# Why class instance return None when it has initialized

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I had a class as below

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'students'

    student_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, address, name):
        self.address = address
        self.name = name
```

below is my call

```
def test_Student(self):
        from School.Student import Student
    address = 'India'
        name = 'Team A'

        student = Student(address,name)
        print student.student_id
```

`student.student_id is returning None`,

why it is returning None ? Shall i write test case as `assertIsNone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `student` object is [transient](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#quickie-intro-to-object-states) and does not have any identity in the database. Assuming `student_id` is generated automatically, it will be `None` till you persist this object in the session.

```
session.add(student)
session.flush()
```

However, if you are writing tests, be careful that you do not commit your session (and hence add test data to the DB). This would involve opening a new transaction for every test and rolling it back at the end of the test

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the student first to get an autoincremented id.

```
session.add(student)
```